# Why are dog belly buttons so different from our own?

Tags: dogs, anatomy

I'm going to assume that no one needs to be told what human belly buttons look like.  But most people probably don't know what dog belly buttons look like.  Here's a photo of one, which should make it easier to understand why we usually don't notice them:

[image]

I'm guessing that the difference between the two has something to do with the way the knot is tied, but is there a more thorough explanation?  Why are dog belly buttons so different from our own?

Answer (score -1):

human birth cords are cut, dogs are not, in essence this is the main difference, caused mainly by mortification of cord leftover and the way humans grow in comparison to dogs;

google some images of children from rural africa/asia and you will find many with belly buttons resembling those of your dog (no exact matches though as we are usually doing something about the cords in one way or another)

Comment: Your second paragraph is off-topic or doesn't make sense at all. However your first paragraph is decent.